# online space to store files using commandline

Tags: command-line, backup

I require a small space online (free) where I can
upload/download few files automatically using a script.
Space requirement is around 50 MB.

This should be such that it could be automated so I can set
it to run without manual interaction i.e. No GUI

I have a dynamic ip & have no tech on setting up a server.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of online storage services provide 1-2 GB space for free. Several of those have command-line clients. E.g. SpiderOak that I use has a client that can run in a headless (non-GUI) mode to upload files, and there's even a way to download files from it by `wget` or `curl`.

You just set up things in GUI mode, then put files into the configured directory and run SpiderOak with right options; files get uploaded. Then you either download ('restore') all or some of the files via another SpiderOak call or get them via HTTP.

About the same applies to Dropbox, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: I dunno, files transfer is [remote -> ONLINE -> home] I cannot install 3rd party apps on remote pc. This catched my eye Share folders instantly in web ShareRooms w / RSS @ SpiderOak

Answer (score 0):

www.bshellz.net gives you a free shell running Linux. I think everyone gets 50mb so you're in luck!

Comment: I get connection timeout when I access directly however I can connect using anonymouse.org

Comment: That's weird... Are you behind a firewall? Bshellz (as far as I know) doesn't block any region of the world, so that shouldn't be a problem...